# Prolog: finding intersection of two lists?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have Prolog facts such as:

```
fact1(x, [y1, y2, y3, y4]).

fact2(z1, [s, t, u, **y3**).
fact2(z2, [o, p, **y1**, q, r]).
fact2(z3, [**y1**, m, **y3**, n]).
fact2(z4, [j, k, **y4**, l]).
fact2(z5, [**y2**, d, e, f, g, h,  i]).
fact2(z6, [a, b, c, **y4**]).
```

And, I want a query such that I get all the 'z' who are related to x.

Thus, this query should output z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6 because they all contain an element y1, y2, y3, and/or y4 because they are related to x in the first Prolog fact.

The following code outputs all of z's relation's of fact2:

```
fact2(_,X).
```

And the following code outputs x's relation of fact1:

```
fact1(x,X).
```

Thus, I figured that I would need to get the intersection of the two sets with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
xyz(X):-
  intersection(fact2(_,X),fact2(x,X),X).
```

This doesn't work, can someone lead me in the right direction?

With the query, what I need to get is: z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6 because they all contain either y1, y2, y3, and/or y4 due to the fact that those are all related to x int he first fact.

If you need clarification, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why not work with the data directly (using lists of lists)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this snippet

```
xyz(L):-
    fact1(x, L1),
    setof(K, L2^I^(fact2(K, L2), intersection(L1,L2,I), I \= []), L).
```

yields

```
?- xyz(L).
L = [z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6].
```

Comment: Thank you, this matches my need. Currently that queries me a list of all the 'z' in a list. If I wanted them to show up individually, as L = [z1] L = [z2] , etc. how would go about that?

Comment: you could take the goal from setof: `xyz(K) :- fact1(x, L1), fact2(K, L2), intersection(L1,L2,I), I \= [].`

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate each term on fact2 and fact1 in a different variable, otherwise you are forcing  the instances to match identically. Also, lose the asterics on the facts "fact2", and close the clasp in the first fact "fact2", after the element y3.
If you wanna keep the asterics, then enclose them between single quotation mark.

```
fact1(x, [y1, y2, y3, y4]).

fact2(z1, [s, t, u, '**y3**']).
fact2(z2, [o, p, y1, q, r]).
fact2(z3, [y1, m, y3, n]).
fact2(z4, [j, k, y4, l]).
fact2(z5, [y2, d, e, f, g, h,  i]).
fact2(z6, [a, b, c, y4]).
xyz(Z):-  fact2(Z,X),fact1(_,Y), intersection(X,Y,I), I\=[].
```

Then try asking:

```
?- xyz(X)
```

or this if you want all the answers in a single list L:

```
?- setof(Z, xyz(Z), L).
```

Comment: Actually xyz(X) gives me: "X = [y3], X = [ ], X = [y1], X = [y1, y3], X = [y4], X = [y2], X = [ ], X = [ ], X = [ ], X = [ ], X = [y4]". What I need it to output is actually z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6. Any ideas? By the way, the asterisks were just there to make those variables 'bold'.

Comment: In that case, replace the predicate xyz for this: xyz(Z):-  fact2(Z,X),fact1(_,Y), intersection(X,Y,I), I\=[]. if you want to obtain all the posible answer in a single list, then use this query: setof(Z, xyz(Z), L).